# ASP.NET Core app only works as root

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I just updated all the Microsoft packages on my ASP.NET core app to the latest 2.1 versions (as well as updated the SDK to 2.1.4 on my CentOS server) and pushed the code to the server. I rebuilt the code server-side and deployed it to the web root. I can't get the server to respond now unless it runs as root. When attempting to connect through the Apache proxy, I get a `502 Proxy Error` and when I attempt to connect directly to the SSL port the Kestrel server is listening on, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` in Chrome.

If I run the site manually as root user (`dotnet WebsiteMainDll.dll`) it works fine. If I run it manually as the user it should run as (`sudo -u siteuser dotnet WebsiteMainDll.dll`), it doesn't work.

There are no errors shown in the console. It just shows `Now listening on https://0.0.0.0:44313` and is silent from that point on.

I have another instance of the site running on the pre-updated codebase and it works fine running as site user. This instance worked fine pre-update. What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps try setting the [verbosity option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21) of `dotnet` and see if you can get more info.

Comment: I'm just getting `unknown option --verbosity` when attempting to run. I tried `dotnet --verbosity diag WebsiteMainDll.dll` and `dotnet --verbosity=diag WebsiteMainDll.dll`. I see the option in the help output, but it won't take it.

Comment: What bout `dotnet -d run WebsiteMainDll.dll`?

Comment: I actually found the issue after I tried to run the `.csproj` instead of the `.dll` and found that NuGet couldn't restore the packages due to an SSL error: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9391

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this was due to permissions issues on some local SSL certificates. I feel either the .NET SDK update installed new packages on my system that messed up permissions, or one of the new ASP.NET Core NuGet packages changed the way SSL is handled in Core.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9391